# Angular does not recognise a selector within Template even if it has been declared in Component

Tags: html, angular, templates, components

I can't work out why Angular will not allow me to reference my components selector. I have a page which when you click on a list item the page should bring up another templates html. This is my code.

The error I keep receiving is 'message-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'message-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'message-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**Messages.component.html**

```
     <div id="Case" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Case</h2>
    <message-case> </message-case>
  </div>
```

I don't understand why it is giving me this error when the Message Component is declared and imported in both the NgModule and within the component.

**Messages.Module.ts**

```
@NgModule
({
    imports: [SharedModule],


    declarations: [
        MessagesComponent,
        MessageCaseComponent,

        MessagesFilterPipe,
        CreateMessageComponent,

    ],

})
```

Finally this is the file I am trying to display using the components selector

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IMessage } from './message';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {MessagesComponent} from './messages.component'; 
import {CreateMessageComponent} from './createmessage.component';
@Component
({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'message-case',
    templateUrl: 'message-case.html'
})
```

All help would be appreciated! I'm seemingly at a dead end right now.

Comment: Can you post your `@Component` definition?

Comment: Did you import the component into the parent component ???

Comment: This is my Messages.Component.ts file
@TeddySterne @Praveen 
`// Import statements
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { IMessage } from './message';
import {MessageCaseComponent} from './message-case.component'; 
import {CreateMessageComponent} from './createmessage.component';
// Metadata and templates
@Component
    ({
        moduleId: module.id,
        templateUrl: 'messages.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['messages.component.css'],
        selector: 'message-component'

       


    })
`

Comment: Can you paste your @Component metadata for parent component or your AppModule

Comment: Components/Directives are not imported. They are added to the NgModule `declarations` and `exports` settings. If you are using a component from *another* module, then you `import` that module.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia All those steps have been followed. The components are declared in my NgModule. The problem is my other components to not recognised the other components selector

Comment: You can not use a component unless it has been declared somewhere by a module that is part of your app. Either a new module, or a module you imported. Angular only knows of components via NgModule. While you can declare imports at the component level. This just helps with tree shaking dependencies.

Comment: Show more of your code. We don't have enough to resolve the error.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I have added more content to my original question! Hope this helps!

Comment: @EdwardMuldrew you have to add your components to the `exports` section of your module. You only have them listed in the `declarations` section. Has to be in both.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I tried that earlier, but had the same error. 
One of the strange things is if I remove the messages.components template url it still directs to the same html page. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia In fact if I remove that HTML file, it gives me an error saying it's failing to load that page even if I have changed the reference of the template URL to something different

Comment: I always start my template paths with `"./"` so try `"./message-case.html"`

Answer (score 0):

Firstable the name file is wrong you putted this filename in the description

**"Messages.component.html"**

And the path of the template must contains "./" if it is in the same folder if it is in another folder you must put the relative path folder/file

```
@Component
({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'message-case',
    templateUrl: './Messages.component.html'
})
```